# Pick highest values in rows which have the same label in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like shown below

| SKU | Stock | Past |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 | 45 |
| ABC | 20 | 30 |
| DEF | 22 | 0 |
| DEF | 5 | 67 |

Basically, I just want to change the value of 'Stock' and 'Past' to just one value and pick the highest, so the result should be:

| SKU | Stock | Past |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 20 | 45 |
| DEF | 22 | 67 |

Is this possible to be done in Pandas? Please advise, anyone. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` "SKU" and use `max` method to find the maximum value of each column in each group:

```
out = df.groupby('SKU').max()
```

Output:

```
     Stock  Past
SKU             
ABC     20    45
DEF     22    67
```